# NSMutableArray property - Release children

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here is what I see when I run the following code:

```
// Dealloc on MyClass not called
MyClass* c = [MyClass new];
self.a = [NSMutableArray new];
[self.a addObject:c];
[c release];
[a release];

// Dealloc on MyClass called
MyClass* c2 = [MyClass new];
NSMutableArray* a2 = [NSMutableArray new];
[a2 addObject:c2];
[c2 release];
[a2 release];

// Dealloc on MyClass called
MyClass* c3 = [MyClass new];
a = [NSMutableArray new];
[a addObject:c3];
[c3 release];
[a release];
```

Why does dealloc not get called in the first example?

EDIT:

I think I was misunderstanding all this.  Basically what I need to do is:

```
NSMutableArray* alocal = [NSMutableArray new]; // alocal has a retain count of 1
self.a = alocal; // a has a retain count of 1
[alocal release]; // alocal has a retain count of 0
[a release]; // a has a retain count of 0
```

OR

```
self.a = [[NSMutableArray new] autorelease]; // a has a retain count of 2
[a release]; // a has a retain count of 0
```

OR

```
self.a = [NSMutableArray array]; // a has a retain count of 2
[a release]; // a has a retain count of 0
```

Just as a note, with the autorelease/array options (#2 and #3), a does not get released right away, so if you want more control go with option #1.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting... So basically you want it to be deallocated right at that moment huh?  Well sounds fair. Normally we just let the pool get released automatically by itself but you are right it won't get released right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the first example, assuming `a` is a retain/copy property, the array leaks.

```
self.a = [NSMutableArray new];
```

which, by the way, is different from the third example:

```
a = [NSMutableArray new];
```

In the third case, the object is assigned directly to the ivar (no property setter involved).

Returning to the first example, the method `new` returns a retained object (+1) and then the property setter retains as well the object (+2). Then, when the property is released (-1), you end up with a +1. This is wrong. You need to balance your retain/releases to end up with a +0.

A simple solution is to use a *convenience constructor*:

```
self.a = [NSMutableArray array];
```

In this case, the method `array` returns an autoreleased object (+0) and the property setter retains the object (+1), which is balanced by the release of the property (-1) and you end up with a +0.

---

Also, in the first example, you release the object you set to the property through the ivar:

```
[a release];
```

As a result, the property is now holding a pointer to a potentially deallocated object. Since you relinquished ownership of the object, there is no guarantee that the object will be alive in the future. If the object was in fact deallocated (because it doesn't have any other owners), your pointer would still point to the memory address in the heap where the object used to live; except that now, that address might contain anything: the old bit pattern of the said object, or an unrelated object, or absolute garbage.

Nothing good can happen if you send a message to the deallocated object, e.g. it will make your app crash. To avoid this, release the object through the property:

```
self.a = nil;
```

Comment: When I do...self.a = [NSMutableArray array]; the dealloc is still not called.  Also when I call...self.a = [[NSMutableArray new] autorelease]; the dealloc is still not called.

Comment: @user472292 Now that the array is not leaking anymore, it should get called. There must be something else going on. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I'm fairly sure the array wasn't leaking.  Before I called [a release] I checked the retain count and it was 1.

Comment: @user472292 how is the property `a` declared? Properties are `assign` by default, so if you don't specify anything, they are `assign`, which is typically used for primitive types and object you do not own like delegates. In this case, it should be `retain` or `copy`, which is the first assumption of my post. So, how it is `a` declared?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* a;

Comment: You mention you need to autorelease the object.  Are you saying that for every property, you need to do this?  Seems odd...

Comment: I think I understand now.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'll update my question with my interpretation.

Comment: @user472292 You are welcome. Another concern is `[a release];`. Please, refer to the last part of my answer.

Comment: @albertamg you should explain why it is a concern. Basically it should be a concern because if later in the code you send a message to `a` the variable is still pointing to the object even tho it was already deallocated and thus it will make your app crash. To fix that you have to assign `nil` to the variable like `a = nil;`. A way to make this cleaner is by doing `self.a = nil` because the setter property does both a `release` and assignment of `nil` for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implemented the property 'a'
It should be:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *a;
```

also when using 'new' it is putting an allocation so you should autorelease it like this:

```
self.a = [[NSMutableArray new] autorelease];
```

Comment: When I do...self.a = [NSMutableArray array]; the dealloc is still not called.  Also when I call...self.a = [[NSMutableArray new] autorelease]; the dealloc is still not called.